# Best method to match words between a list and a dictionary, returning only the ones that are unique for a key without the use of modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing this script where `archive` contains the words that a person has said and their age, and `clues` are sentences where some words are extracted to  match with the most likely person that said them. Words that work as a clue are marked with a `*` and all `clues` should be uniquely used by a person.

```
from typing import List, Dict, TextIO, Tuple
def who_did_it(archive: Dict[str, List[tuple]], clues: str) -> str:

    word_list = []
    #contains person and a list of its words in a list 
    clean_clue = get_words(clues)
    #get_words: extract the clues clean into a list without the `*`
    suspect = []
    #a list for the most likely person that did it
    dict_list = {}
    #person as key, a list of words as values

    for people in archive:
        clues = archive.get(people)
        word_list.append([people, get_words(clues[0])])
        clean_clue.sort()
        for person, words in word_list:
            dict_list.setdefault(person, words)

    numb = 0
    for names in dict_list:
        for clues in clean_clue:
            if clues in dict_list.get(names):
                numb = numb + 1
            elif tags not in dict_list.get(names):
                numb = numb - 1
        if numb == 1:
            suspect.append(names)
            counter = 0

    if len(suspect) == 1:
        print(suspect[0])
    else:
        print('need more evidence')
```

The problem comes when I use my test cases, some of them doesn't seem to work because of the way I'm doing it, is there any other way to compare this values? How can I compare this values in an efficient way without using modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off using a dict with keys that are your clues/weapons and sets of names as values:

```
def who(things,clues):
    """ Returns a sorted list of (name, [clues,...]) tuples, sorted by longest len first"""
    result = {}
    for t in things:
        for name in clues[t]:
            result.setdefault(name,[])
            result[name].append(t)

    return sorted(result.items(), key=lambda x:-len(x[1]))


clues = { "knife":{"Joe","Phil"}, "club":{"Jane","John"}, "ice":{"Joe","Neffe"}}
print(who({"knife","ice"}, clues))
```

Output:

```
[('Joe', ['knife', 'ice']), ('Phil', ['knife']), ('Neffe', ['ice'])]
```

The reason the other way round is better: you are looking for the clues - which should be the keys.

Comment: yeah that's what I did, it was better to have clues as keys and the names as values; now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is mixed up with the parsing which is not a very good thing. If you separate them things are much easier to understand.

```
from typing import List, Dict

def get_words(sentence: str) -> List:
    return [word[1:] for word in sentence.split() if word.startswith('*')]

def who_did_it(archive: Dict[str, List[str]], clues: List[str]) -> str:

    suspect = []
    #a list for the most likely person that did it

    for name, belongings in archive.items():
        if all(clue in belongings for clue in clues):
            suspect.append(name)

    if len(suspect) == 1:
        print(suspect[0])
    else:
        print('need more evidence')

facts = {
        'martin': ('I had a knife and a *broom', 22), 
        'jose': ('I had a *knife', 21),
        }

archive = { name : get_words(fact[0]) for name, fact in facts.items()}   
who_did_it(archive, get_words('he had a *knife'))
```